# single-row subquery returns more than one row : ORA-01427

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
UPDATE DESIGNATION_REVISED A SET A.DCODE_ORG=(SELECT D.DCODE_ORG FROM DESIGNMAST_DUP D WHERE D.DNAME=A.DNAME)
```

The above `update` throws

> single-row subquery returns more than one row : ORA-01427

Comment: It is what is says - your subquery e.g. `SELECT D.DCODE_ORG FROM DESIGNMAST_DUP D WHERE D.DNAME=A.DNAME` returns more than one `DCODE_ORG` for specific `DNAME` - check your data ...  change your subquery to return single row ...

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `DESIGNMAST_DUP`  table names are duplicate so inner query returns more than one row.
Try this:-

```
UPDATE DESIGNATION_REVISED A SET A.DCODE_ORG=(SELECT distinct D.DCODE_ORG FROM DESIGNMAST_DUP D WHERE D.DNAME=A.DNAME)
```